# Do bison conceal their pregnancy?

Tags: biology, zoology

Today there is an [article](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/oct/21/first-wild-bison-born-in-uk-for-millennia-after-surprise-pregnancy) in The Guardian that states

> Three bison were released in Kent in July but, unknown to the rangers, one had a secret passenger on board. Bison conceal their pregnancies to prevent predators targeting pregnant animals or their offspring.

I got interested in this and tried to find a source that explains how a bison would conceal pregnancy - but I couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't think there is any actual concealing needed. A pregnant bison doesn't look very different from a slightly more well fed one. So a typical human can't really see the difference. Could you distinguish a pregnant cow from an unpregnant one?

Comment: @quarague *I* can't, but a ranger (or in case of a cow, a farmer) should be much better at this than I am…

Comment: @gerrit: That intrigued me. I am not particularly vouching for [this source](https://farmhouseguide.com/signs-a-cow-is-pregnant/) but it says "It can be difficult to spot a pregnant cow among your herd", and suggests the "bump" shows up late - and includes some subtle tell-tales (and, of course, medical tests).

Comment: @gerrit A good source on that could be a reasonable answer to this question but my impression was that even for a cow farmer this is non-trivial and much more difficult than spotting a human pregnancy.

Comment: Many animals use small as their strongest sense. For instance, some predators can smell a slight amount of blood at distance that would not be possible for humans. Perhaps they are somehow disguising their scent?

Comment: @quarague, vets detect pregnant cows (cattle) by hand, while wearing a rubber glove that goes all the way up to the shoulders. And people with short arms become pet vets, not farm vets.

Comment: "Conceal" implies intent, anthropomorphizing the animals.  I guess an objective version of the claim might be simply that humans and/or predators have difficulty determining whether a bison is pregnant.

Comment: The reporter is on Twitter, it should be easy enough to reach him and ask for the source of his claim.

Comment: @NateEldredge if an animal puts some food somewhere out of reach of competitors do we need to avoid ascribing intent to the animal because only humans can have intent?  The reason it makes little sense to ascribe intent to a pregnant bison is that she has no control over her appearance.  The same is true, however, of animals with camouflage fur, feathers, or what have you, but there's no reason to avoid the word "conceal" with such animals.

Comment: Related - [other animals, such as giraffes, do it too](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2017/03/02/how-long-do-have-watch-giraffe-before-has-its-baby/98635994/). With giraffes they're not purposefully concealing it, rather it's naturally hard to tell unless you know what to look for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article is about wild bison in the UK - so the [European bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_bison) (*Bison bonasus*). It is also known as Żubr in Polish, which comes up later.

I found this question was disputed in an article from *1958* - but gives hints as to where the claim may have originated from.

- Jaczewski, Zbigniew, [*Reproduction of the European Bison, Bison bonasus (L.), in Reserves*](https://rcin.org.pl/ibs/dlibra/publication/edition/8966), 1958, Acta Theriologica Vol 1, Issue 9, pp333-376

On p7, Jaczewski writes:

> Pregnancy is said to last 9 months (Brincken, 1929; Karcov, 1903; Wróblewski, 1927). **The condition of a gravid cow can be recognized
> by its external appearance** (Wróblewski, 1927)<sup>2</sup>.

So the 1958 author says you *can* tell that a European Bison is pregnant ("gravid"), and justifies that with an even earlier reference:

- Wróblewski, Konrad, [*Żubr Puszczy Białowieskiej*](https://rcin.org.pl/ibs/dlibra/publication/edition/2547). Poznań, 1927.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to this book, so I don't know what evidence they have to support this claim. [I see this as a weakness to this answer.]

But wait... the original quote from the 1958 source has a footnote:

> Karcov claims that a gravid cow cannot be recognized by her appearance, which, however, is not correct.

Oooh! Controversy!

That source is:

- Karcov G (1903) Belovezhskaya Pushcha. Ee istoricheskii ocherk, sovremennoe okhotniche khozaistvo i vysochaishe okhoty v Pushche [Białowieża Forest. Its historical description, contemporary game management and monarchical hunts in the forest]. A. Marks, St. Petersburg, 414 (in Russian)

Alas, I haven't found the text for this either.

To summarise:

- 1903: Forest Game management expert says you can't tell if a cow is pregnant.
- 1927: Żubr expert says you can tell.
- 1958: Another Żubr expert says (with no justification provided) that the first one is wrong, the second one is right.

I am hoping we can find some more verifiable evidence, but this was sufficient for me to tentatively accept experts can tell, and that there is at least one source in the literature that could explains why people think you can't.

Comment: None of these mention when during the pregnancy they are talking about. If they are talking about the last month or the first month, the appearance might be noticeably different. But perhaps the first month doesn't look much different from the second-last.

Comment: @RayButterworth on top of that, I reckon almost anyone can recognize a bison pregnancy in the last hour or so.